# PLCrashReporter not compiling in Xcode 10 beta 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode10, plcrashreporter

PLCrashReporter not compiling in Xcode 10 beta. Seems like register size issue.

error: invalid operand for instruction movq %cs, 160(%rsp);

error: invalid operand for instruction movq %fs, 168(%rsp);

error: invalid operand for instruction movq %gs, 176(%rsp);

I did follow this link https://github.com/plausiblelabs/plcrashreporter/pull/12/files after doing code changes the other instructions are getting error.

error: invalid operand for instruction movl %cs, 16 +56(%esp);

error: invalid operand for instruction movl %ds, 16 +60(%esp);

error: invalid operand for instruction movl %es, 16 +64(%esp);

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: did you find a resolution to this yet?

Comment: You might want to consider going with Microsoft's fork: https://github.com/Microsoft/PLCrashReporter

Answer (score 0):

It seems that beta 5 have a lot bugs.

Mine is `ln` error

beta 1~4 all works fine. plus Xcode 9

Answer (score 0):

Use this version which fixes some of the issues from the author's repository

https://github.com/Microsoft/PLCrashReporter

If you like to use the original version, replace following in `PLCrashAsyncThread_current.S` file (around line number 149) as reported [here](https://github.com/plausiblelabs/plcrashreporter/pull/12)

```
#if 0
MOVL    (cs, 56);
MOVL    (ds, 60);
MOVL    (es, 64);
MOVL    (fs, 68);
MOVL    (gs, 72);
#undef MOVL
#else
movl    $0, 56(%esp);
movw    %cs, 56+OFF(%esp);
movl    $0, 60(%esp);
movw    %ds, 60+OFF(%esp);
movl    $0, 64(%esp);
movw    %es, 64+OFF(%esp);
movl    $0, 68(%esp);
movw    %fs, 68+OFF(%esp);
movl    $0, 72(%esp);
movw    %gs, 72+OFF(%esp);
#endif
```

Note that, this will only resolve it partially. PLCR still uses some deprecated functions for spinlocks and memory barrier that need to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try change `MOVQ` to `movw` from line 96 to line 98 in `PLCrashAsyncThread_current.S`,like this:

```
movw    %cs, 160(%rsp);
movw    %fs, 168(%rsp);
movw    %gs, 176(%rsp);
```

more info check [here](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Clang-x86-64-can-t-move-segment-registers-tp4060881p4060882.html)

ps,there is anothre error in the file, you can check the solution from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/plcrashreporter/pull/12#issuecomment-414185014) which *yumoji* mentioned.

Best wishes!